# Page break in LaTeX only if a code block is split between pages

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex

I'm writing a report in LaTeX that contains several code blocks of varying sizes. For example, a code block might be:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
    dic = {
        "qwe": 0.2,
        "wer": 0.3,
        "ert": 0.1,
        "rty": 0.1,
        "tyu": 0.1,
        "yui": 0.2
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

When I add new text paragraphs, sections, etc., the code block moves around (obviously). Sometimes, the end of a page cuts the block, resulting in some of the block hanging over into a new page.

[image: broken code block]

Instead of manually writing `\pagebreak` above `\begin{lstlisting}`, I'm wondering if there's some way to tell LaTeX to page break right above the code block only if not doing so would cause the block to be cut off by the end of a page.

That way, if the code block fits perfectly where it is, there won't be an unnecessary page break.

I hope this makes sense, thanks for the help.

Comment: You might be better off asking on [tex.se].

Comment: The answers to this question may help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Thanks @Dugnom!